# Cant build a docker dart-runtime image after a local pub-get

Tags: docker, dart, symlink, file-not-found

I m new to docker, and i m using the *[google/dart-runtime](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart-runtime/)* base image on arch.

Everything works fine except when i do a ***pub get*** before building the image (i need it for webstorm code completion) then i have to delete every "package" symlink to be able to build my image again.

if not, i get this error:

```
sudo docker build -t foo/myapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 9.952 MB
Step 1 : FROM google/dart-runtime
# Executing 4 build triggers...
Step 1 : ADD pubspec.* /app/
stat packages/_discoveryapis_commons: no such file or directory
```

Note: _discoveryapis_commons is the 1st package of the list, i don't think it's related to him specifcally...

How can i do a *pub get* outside of the container without messing up the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly causes the error but I see two "workarounds":

- use `pub get --no-package-symlinks`. This is still experimental but works fine as long as you don't have external tools that depend on the `packages` symlinks. Also the `test` package still doesn't work fully without the `packages` directory.
- create a `.dockerignore` file with `packages/*` as content

Comment: pub get --no-package-symlinks works like a charm! Thanks! :)

Comment: This is planned to become the default anyway when everything is fixed so the test package works properly this way. Probably with Dart 1.14

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is creating a *[.dockerignore](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)* file at the root of your project and write inside:

```
*packages/*
```